# How to put() values into Guava's Cache class?

Tags: java, guava

I'm a little confused by [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) introduced in Guava 10. The documentation hints that it's possible to [overwrite values](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterWrite-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) but as far as I can tell, [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) does not contain any methods for doing so. Any ideas?

I'm trying to construct a Map that expires a key 10 seconds after it was last read or written-to. When a value is looked up, I expect the previously-set value to be returned, or a default value to be computed if none exists.

**NOTE**: This question is outdated. Although the above Javadoc shows the existence of a `Cache.put(K key, V value)` method, it not exist when the question was first posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since long, there's `Cache#asMap` returning a `ConcurrentMap` view.

<strike>AFAIK, not yet. But there's a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/6uC0IySW0rM) mentioning that `Cache.asMap.put` is planned for release 11.</strike>

I'd say the <strike>current</strike> old state of the Javadoc is a remnant if the `CacheBuilder`'s evolution from the `MapMaker` (where the cache-setting method are currently deprecated).

> I'm trying to construct a Map that expires a key 10 seconds after it was last read or written-to. When a value is looked up, I expect the previously-set value to be returned, or a default value to be computed if none exists.

Using `expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` will keep an entry alive for 10 seconds after any access to it. And the only values you'll get are those computed by your `CacheLoader` (either earlier or during `get`).

Comment: Guava 10.0.1 should have fixed this. http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f01f7583bb4422d7

Answer (score 3):

Minor update. `Cache.asMap().put()` should show up in Guava 10.1 sometime during the first week of October, 2011. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/725ed98dd25efbd5) for more info.